# Efficient way to store form data?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, forms

I have a web app that has a big and complex form (fields, checks, etc).
I hade using standard OS form controls because they have visual (styling) limits.

I have been basically creating spans with IDs and attaching class or custom data attributes. I later need to send this to a PHP script for insertion into a database. This has worked well in the past, but I'm having to do a lot of manual processing of fields, which I don't think is efficient... Is there a better way?

I currently do,

```
IF ($('#foo').hasClass('on')){bar=1}
```

...

Then I manually compose a POST string via

```
foo=bar&bla=blabla ...
```

Then lots more on the PHP side to create an insert SQL statement.
Seems like its inefficient if you have dozens of fields... But I hate standard FORM elements...

Any suggestions? .... Loops? Arrays?

Comment: you could serialize the form data before sending.

Comment: What are the visual (styling) limits you are referring to? You can change the look of form elements [using css](http://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/).

Comment: what's your reason for hating standard `form` elements?

Comment: 327: a few limitation that the client wants to avoid, ie. click on a box once, Green check, twice Red check. Etc. I know I could use drop downs but it's all about the visual. I found I get lots more control by adding class styles to spans or table cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

```
$('form .on').serialize();
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/KF3ZB/1/)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I also works with dynamic tables if you have name=foo[] ... THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a form. But how to make it pretty?

With JavaScript you can have a kind of front-end for the form. Hide the form elements and have some JS that changes the form field values on interaction.

Search for `pretty forms jquery` in Google.

Comment: Pretty, yes but also added functionality. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Just want to avoid manually setting each element to a variable.

Comment: You should use a form. Lets say you want a range picker with a slider. The values should be stored in to text input fields. When you have javascript active, you hide the input fields and show some interactive graphics as a slider. When you move the slider, the javascript will automatically change the value of the regarding input field. That makes the slider form an encapsulated 'thing' and you don't have to worry about it on the server side. If you don't have JavaScript, just the two text fields show, which degraded gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you don't want to manually get the value of each element that has the class 'on'. You could use jQuery's each function looping through all the elements you need. Something like:

```
​var query = "";

$(".on")​​.each(function(i){
    if(i === 0) {  
      query+="?"+$(this).attr('id')+"="+$(this).text();            
    } else {
        query+="&"+$(this).attr('id')+"="+$(this).text();            
    }
});
```

(see: http://jsfiddle.net/MkbrV/)

Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: Looks like I just need to be smart about naming my IDs as the relate to database fields so I will have an easier time on the PHP side as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that they somehow relate to the db.